# Reducing a list of strings to known signature strings

Tags: string-manipulation

I have a list consisting of string signatures:

```
lis1 = {"ab","cd","ef","gh"}
```

I have another list:

```
lis2 = {"ab","efij","cde"}
```

I would like to find elements in `lis2` that begin with known signatures in `lis1` and then replace them with the corresponding signatures from `lis1` to get:

```
res = {"ab", "ef", "cd"}
```

Hopefully, this is clearly stated. Please let me know if it isn't.

Comment: **I would like to take elements in lis2 that begin with strings in lis1 and replace them with the corresponding element from lis1** what happens if lis1 has two such hits and not just one?

Comment: Thanks Nasser, good question - see my comments below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be some edge cases to consider, but you might approach it as follows. Create a replacement rule for each element of lis1 (and keep a list of such rules):

```
replaceRules = (# ~~ ___ -> #) & /@ lis1
```

Now use this list of rules in StringReplace:

```
StringReplace[lis2, replaceRules]
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  This fails with lis1= {"abcd","defg", "defghij"} and lis2 = {"abcd", "defgxyz", "defghijxyz"}.  It produces res = {"abcd","defg","defg"} instead of the desired res = {"abcd","defg","defghij"}

Comment: That’s one of the edge cases I mentioned. You probably need to sort lis1 by length (longest first).

Answer (score 2):

Using `SubsetQ`:

```
StringJoin @@@ 
 First /@ Select[Tuples[{Characters[lis1], Characters[lis2]}]
   , SubsetQ[Last@#, First@#] &]
```

> `{"ab", "cd", "ef"}`

Comment: Also thanks! This approach  with the same lis1 and lis2 in the comment above yields res = {"abcd","defg","defg","defghij"} instead of the desired res = {"abcd","defg","defghij"}

Comment: A `Union` command can fix it: `StringJoin @@@ 
 Union@(First /@ Select[Tuples[{Characters[lis1], Characters[lis2]}]
     , SubsetQ[Last@#, First@#] &])`

Comment: Syed, thanks for your reply.  I've found another edge where your solution does not provide the desired result. lis1 = {"defg", "defghij"} and lis2 = {"defghijxyz"}.  Your solution yields {"defg", "defghij"}, where the desired solution would be just {"defghij"}.  Grateful for any further thoughts.

Comment: You will need to start with the longest unique signature in `lis1` if that is what you want.